# How to make work modal widnow and slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with slider which is placed inside the modal window.
I have placed images in each different modal-body, in modal body i put code for slider but it's not working. How correctly to apply slider for modal window? This is what i tried so far.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" ><img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_1.png"></a>

    <div class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">

                                <img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_1.png">
                                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                </a>
                                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" ><img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_1.png"></a>

    <div class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">

                                <img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_1.png">
                                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                </a>
                                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to add to your markup to get the ball rolling.

**1.** Add a target to the `href` in the anchors in order to toggle the modal

```
    Change: 
     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal"></a>
    To:
     <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"></a>
```

**2.** Add `id` from step **1** to the modal you want to toggle

```
    Change: 
     <div class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    To:
     <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

**3.** Close the `carousel-inner` right after the last `item`. In the current markup, the prev/next controls are inside this div and they need to be pulled out.

Below is a code snippet with these changes. I've only applied the changes to one of the modals from your html, but you can apply the same changes to any other modals that you might have in your page.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_1.png" alt="Open Modal"></a>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x200">
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x200">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
Using multiple images and multiple modals

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="portfolio-layout">
  <div class="portfolio-wrap carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="portfolio_grid">


          <div class="mix col-md-4 col-sm-6 office">

            <a href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_1.png" alt="Open Modal"></a>

            <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span>×</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">Title</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="my-slider1" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x150/ffcccc">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item ">
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x150/ccffcc">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider1" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="mix col-md-4 col-sm-6 office">

            <a href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_2.png" alt="Open Modal"></a>

            <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span>×</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Title</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="my-slider2" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x150/ccccff">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item ">
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x150/ff2233">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="mix col-md-4 col-sm-6 office">
            <a href="#myModal3" data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_3.png" alt="Open Modal"></a>

            <div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span>×</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel3">Title</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="my-slider3" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x150/556677">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item ">
                          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x150/55ffaa">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider3" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: thank you, but one problem images not switching on click its automatically looping them. I put same image link in both tags "item active" and "item"

Comment: And even if i fully copy you code the its only switch images automatically but buttons doesn't work

Comment: @Viktor In the snippet above, the images only switch when either the prev or next buttons are clicked due to the `data-interval="false"`. Is that the behavior you get when you press the > `Run code snippet` button above? If you want the images to scroll automatically then you need to swap  `data-interval="false"` for `data-ride="carousel"`.

Comment: i need to switch images by clicking next/prev button, i think the problem is that images is not next to each other, they located in each separated col-md tag with all the code listed above

Comment: @Viktor I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, could you post a pic that shows what you have in mind?

Comment: this is the structure of my code, so only one picture must be located in  <div class="mix col-md-4 col-sm-6 office"> https://pastebin.com/i4gFLXrv

Comment: @Viktor I've updated my answer to include multiple images and modals. Note that every element should have a unique `id` whereas in your code right now, there are elements with duplicate ids. Also, for the images to scroll, you need more than one image inside the slider. Here is an example in bootply of the same updated code https://www.bootply.com/kDguyR2do5